# Не генерируются pdb-символы

Tags: c#, отладка

Может я что-то не так понимаю, но суть в чем. Я пишу библиотеку, ее нельзя скомпилить напрямую как мне подсказала студия, поэтому я создал проект и подключил эту библиотеку. Но когда пытаюсь отладить, точка останова не срабатывает, так как нет загруженных файлов символов. Почему?

P.S. Зашел в папку где должны кешироваться символы, а там папка FailedLoads, в ней файл с названием моей библиотеки и в нем "PDB Not Found".

Comment: библиотека моя, все условия выполнены но все равно не работает

Comment: Извиняюсь, все заработало. Когда запускаю то пишет что символы не загружены и попадание в точку останова не произойдет, но как только код доходит до точки, то все работает. Не знаю почему так но все заработало, спасибо!